# How to solve the string replace fiasco

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, string-formatting, stringbuilder

**NOTE** : My problem is NOT that my links are not being replaced. But, it's being **NESTED**.
eg, this is the comment

```
some string with www.google.com/blah/blah also something else www.google.com
```

by the time second string replace is done, part of first one is also valid (**www.google.com**/blah/blah) so it's replacing that link twice.

I have a web app which lets users comment.
I am processing the input string and converting all links to html link format **when I display it on the page**. Original user input string stays in DB and nothing ever happens so it's not corrupted over processing. Just when I show that on page, I do my function on it.

Now, this is the logic I am using to replace all links with their html formats

1. Regex all links
2. For each match, replace link with it's html format version in the original string.
3. Finally display string.

ex: `www.google.com` becomes `<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">www.google.com</a>` just before it's displayed on page.

This was working great until recently, one of my customer posted a content with two links from same domain.

the links were, say,

1. www.google.com/images/blahblah
2. www.google.com

My problem is, when the second time around, a string replace is done (I am using `StringBuilder.Replace`) the first link gets replaced as well!

so, firstly,

```
www.google.com/images/blahblah
```

becomes

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/images/blahblah" target="_blank">www.google.com/image/blahblah</a>
```

which is well. But the problem arises for second string replace, since replace is global, it does a replace on already processed link so the original (above) link becomes twisted as it sees **www.google.com** in there as well.

This is messing up so much that I actually get a mutilated abomination of a string.

How do I avoid this?

Does the `Regex.Matches` provide an index of matched element for me to work with? I couldn't find it anywhere.

What's the best way to deal with? any suggestions?

sorry for lengthy question.

I can prolly do this by manually traversing string but it's long and painful there's got to be a good way to do it...

**edit**  adding extra info as someone asked:

My regex:

```
    string rPattern = @"(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)|www\.)[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#!]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?";

     Regex rLinks = new Regex(rPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     MatchCollection matches = rLinks.Matches(inputString);
```

then I am using

```
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    if(match.value.StartsWith("www.youtube.com/watch"))
    {
         //logic to embed youtube video - this works fine.
    } 
}

//Here I replace all hyperlinks to their <a href> parts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Regex.Matches` returns a `MatchCollection`.  `Match.Index` Is what you're looking for.

```
string pattern = @"(https?://)?(?:www(?:\.\w+)+|(?:\w+\.)+(?:com|org|us|net|...))(/\w*)*"; // your pattern here.
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches (input, pattern))
{
   // Use match.Index and match.Length;
}
```

But really, you're probably looking for something more like this:

```
string originalPost = 
   @"Ooh shiney: www.google.com/images/blahblah
   Look here: www.google.com";

string html = Regex.Replace (
   originalPost, patternString, 
   "<a href='http://$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
```

Or, you can use a matchEvaluator to do more advanced work (like ensure we don't add a double http://.

```
string html = Regex.Replace (
   originalPost, patternString, 
   m => 
      string.Format (
         "<a href='{0}{1}' target='_blank'>{1}</a>",
          m.Value.StartsWith ("http", StringComparison.IgnoreCase) ? "" : "http://",
          m.Value));
```

Comment: Hi, this looks amazing, only, I dont understand much, where can I read more about this? like, what does $1 mean here? will it replace all instances? what is matchEvaluator etc.

Comment: `$1` gets replaced with with the first group.  I should have said `$0` with gets replaced with the whole match.  `MatchEvaluator` is a delegate that gets called for each match - you return the string you want to replace the match with.

Comment: Hi @aget-j, what if I want to include ``https`` as a condition in the MatchEvaluator?, like, startswith("http") OR ("https")

Comment: @LocustHorde, great idea.  It's getting kind of long in lambda syntax, so you should probably move that logic to a separate function.  (by the way, `https` starts with `http`  ;-)

Comment: Touché, ``https`` does indeed start with ``http``. Will see what I can do. Also, found a small bug, your ``string.Format( "a href="http://{0}{1}..."`` includes a http there, and the evaluator adds another http. It should only be ``<a href="{0}{1}.."`` Right?

Comment: one final request (Sorry!) some of my links contain youtube video, how can I modify my pattern to exclude all links containing ``www.youtube.com/watch`` ?

Comment: @LocustHorde, in your replacement MatchEvaluator delegate, just check to see if it's youtube... if it's youtube, just return `match.Value` so effectively no replacement occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need and this is what I've been using for the past couple years now:

```
public static string MakeCommentSafe(string strComment)
{
    // Replace carriage return / line feeds with line feeds.  Then HtmlEncode.  Then replace multiple consecutive line feeds with single line feeds.
    strComment = Regex.Replace(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(Regex.Replace(strComment, "\r\n", "\n").Replace((char)13, (char)10)), "\n(\n)+", "$1\n");

    // Find all links and make them active
    return Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(strComment, @"((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)", "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">$1</a>"), "\n", "<br />");
}
```

And here's a tip.  If you really want this to perform well with lots of comments on the page, then store both the unsafe and safe versions in the database when the comment is posted.  That way you don't have to call this function repeatedly when displaying every comment on a page.

Comment: Hi, why is the ``Regex.Replace`` nested twice?

Comment: @LocustHorde - I'm doing a couple things at a time on each line.  You could certainly break it out into distinct lines if you wanted to.

Comment: oh I see it now, first you are converting links and then converting new lines to ``<br>``..

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) method, e.g.:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "<a href=\"$0\" target=\"_blank\">$0</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

To play devils advocate:

So, you want to correct strings that look like:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/foo/bar
www.example.co.tw/baz.moo?foo=1
```

but, not strings that look like:

www.example.com
   www.example.com/foo/bar
   www.example.co.tw/baz.moo?foo=1

I would guess that I am correct. Simple solution, expand your regex to look either side of the thing that looks like a URL and to ignore it if it:

1. Is between a `href="` and a `" target="_blank">`
2. Is between a `" target="_blank">` and a `</a>`

Comment: Hi, sorry, I want to match everything. In addition to just matching links I am matching youtube videos (which is a subset of links) and converting them to videos too.